# Marshalling my C++ .dll in C# with "const char*" and "const int"

Tags: c#, c++, marshalling

Having in C++:

```
extern "C" MY_API int connect(const char* pcHost,const int nPort, ConnectionId_T *pConId);
```

Being:

- `pcHost` an IP
- `nPort` a port
- `pConId`  a constant (-1)

My try is:

```
[DllImport("my.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern int connect(StringBuilder pcHost, int nPort, ConnectionId_T pConId);
```

But when I try to connect:

```
StringBuilder ip = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
ip.Append("1.1.1.1");
int nPort = 1111;
ConnectionId_T nConId = MY_NCONID // This is defined previously as -1 (public const int MY_NCONID = -1)
connect(ip, nPort, nConId))
```

I get an **AccesViolationException** on the `connect` line. Do I've my marshal wrong?

PS: `ConectionId_T` is defined as `using ConnectionId_T = System.Int32;`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30028593/const-char-in-c

Comment: @codroipo I also tried `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]` and I get the same error.

Comment: you will also have to add attribute to your method defination `[DllImport("yourdll.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]`

Comment: @MujahidDaudKhan That's already included on the original post.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
[DllImport("my.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi,CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int connect(IntPtr pcHost, int nPort, ref ConnectionId_T pConId);
```

and use `Intptr pcHost = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(pcHostString))`

Comment: Why are you changing `pConId` to an `int` when it's originally a `ConnectionId_T`?

Comment: Does it makes any difference?

Comment: How can I convert the string of the IP to a `IntPtr ` so I can make it work?

Comment: by calling this method as explained above [Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(string s)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.stringtohglobalansi(v=vs.100).aspx#Anchor_0)

Comment: It worked by adding `out` before `pConId` as the `.dll` returns the value on that variable. Thanks!

Comment: i think that it would also work with `ref int pConId `

Answer (score -1):

```
PS: ConectionId_T is defined as using ConnectionId_T = System.Int32;
```

Based on this, if I assume `ConnectionId_T` is nothing but `int` in C++ world, then you need to change the function import as:

```
[DllImport("my.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern int connect(StringBuilder pcHost, int nPort, IntPtr pConId);
```

Or as:

```
[DllImport("my.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern int connect(StringBuilder pcHost, int nPort, ref int pConId);
```