# access violation exception while calling the c++ code from c#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to use phash library using this wrapper https://github.com/ludoviclefevre/phash-integration-in-csharp

c++ header:

```
int ph_dct_imagehash(const char* file,ulong64 &hash)
```

c# dll import:

```
DllImport(@"pHash.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern int ph_dct_imagehash(string file, ref ulong hash);
```

test code:

```
ulong hash = 0; 
foreach (var file in files) 
{
    ph_dct_imagehash(file, ref hash);

    dictionary.Add(file, hash);
}
```

It works perfectly for few picture, but when ther's about 200-300 pictures i got Accesviolation exception

```
Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
```

My first lead is garbage collector but i'm confused.. should i use intpr instead of string and hash parameters? I tried changing ref parameter to out but it doesn't matter..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30028680/1870760 instruct the Marshaller how it should pass the file argument with `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]`.

Comment: No, the declaration is correct and LPStr is already the default.  You need to debug the native code to find out why it bombed.  Project > Properties > Debugging > tick "Enable native code debugging".  A memory leak is not unlikely btw, error checking is rudimentary in that library so a failed malloc() will AVE.  Also easily caused by your own code, forgetting to use Image.Dispose() in a C# program is a very traditional bug.